# Arduino c# application light led stop led with c#

Tags: c#, arduino

//Im writting a proggram and one of the things that i have to do is to light the first led on the arduino with the button and then stop with the c# visual studio button .
The question is why when i start the program and i press the button in the C# application the arduiono led doesn't turn off? I don't where is the problem in the arduino side or the visual studio.And what can i do to improve it.

//this is my arduino code

```
const int BUTTON_SWITCH = 8;
const int BUTTON_ALARM = 9;
const int POT = A0;
const int RED_LED = 4;
const int BUZZER =3;
int index = 0;
double value;
int state = 0;
unsigned long time_now = 0;
int period =1000;


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(BUTTON_SWITCH, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(BUTTON_ALARM, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(RED_LED,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
 if(digitalRead(BUTTON_SWITCH)==LOW && state == 0){
  digitalWrite(RED_LED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BUZZER,HIGH);
 }
 float reset;
 reset = Serial.parseFloat();
 if(reset == 0){
  digitalWrite(RED_LED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BUZZER,LOW);
 }



// and here is the code from visual studio

 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.WriteLine("0");
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having or what question you're trying to answer. Please edit your question to clarify the issue you're having and what you've tried so far.

Comment: In c# you are sending the character "0" which is a 0x30.  The character "1" is 0x31.  So you have to test in Adruino for these two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be look like this :

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if(Serial.available()>0)
  {


String incomingByte=Serial.readString();

if(incomingByte=="0")
{
 digitalWrite(RED_LED,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(BUZZER,LOW);

}
  }
}
```